# Filter a grid's data using a selected value in combo box

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid and a combo box in a panel. I was trying to filter the data in the grid based on the selection made in the combo box. I am using ExtJS 4.2.1

Suppose I have a grid with data like this:

[image]

On selecting a particular value in combo box, I want only those values to be displayed in the grid.

if "aaa" is selected then I want it to be displayed as:

[image]

Initially I am loading the grid's data from database using php file.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

P.S. : I dont want the data to be loaded every time I select the combo box item. I just want it to be filtered.

Comment: i hope ur attachment/screen shot is missing, unable to see the output of statement, "Suppose I have a grid with data like this" and "if "aaa" is selected then I want it to be displayed as:"

Comment: All pictures are visible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need a combobox that will also allow you to clear your filter. So you will need a second button on the combobox which allows you to clear if a filter is active. For that you don't need to do much because the framework already cover such a feature, even if it is not documented.

Here's a older version but it should still work on 4.2

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.field.FilterCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.filtercombo',
    /**
    * @cfg {string} recordField
    * @required
    * The fieldname of the record that contains the filtervalue
    */

    /**
    * @cfg {string} searchField
    * @required
    * The fieldname on which the filter should be applied
    */

    /**
    * @cfg {boolean} clearable
    * Indicates if the clear trigger should be hidden. Defaults to <tt>true</tt>.
    */
    clearable: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        // never submit it
            me.submitValue = false;
        if (me.clearable)
            me.trigger2Cls = 'x-form-clear-trigger';
        else
            delete me.onTrigger2Click;

        me.addEvents(

            /**
            * @event clear
            *
            * @param {Ext.ux.form.field.FilterCombo} FilterCombo The filtercombo that triggered the event
            */
            'clear',
            /**
            * @event beforefilter
            *
            * @param {Ext.ux.form.field.FilterCombo} FilterCombo The filtercombo that triggered the event
            * @param {String/Number/Boolean/Float/Date} value The value to filter by
            * @param {string} field The field to filter on
            */
            'beforefilter'
        );

        me.callParent(arguments);
        // fetch the id the save way
        var ident = me.getId();

        me.on('select', function (me, rec) {
            var value = rec[0].data[me.recordField],
                field = me.searchField;
            me.fireEvent('beforefilter', me, value, field)
            me.onShowClearTrigger(true); 
            me.onSearch(value, field);
        }, me);
        me.on('afterrender', function () { me.onShowClearTrigger(); }, me);
    },

    /**
    * @abstract onSearch
    * running a search on the store that may be removed separately
    * @param {String/Number/Boolean/Float/Date} val The value to search for
    * @param {String} field The name of the Field to search on
    */
    onSearch: Ext.emptyFn,

    /**
    * @abstract onFilterRemove
    * removing filters from the the
    * @param {Boolean} silent Identifies if the filter should be removed without reloading the store
    */
    onClear: Ext.emptyFn,

    onShowClearTrigger: function (show) {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.clearable)
            return;
        show = (Ext.isBoolean(show)) ? show : false;
        if (show) {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.setWidth(el.originWidth, false);
                    el.setVisible(true);
                    me.active = true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            me.triggerEl.each(function (el, c, i) {
                if (i === 1) {
                    el.originWidth = el.getWidth();
                    el.setWidth(0, false);
                    el.setVisible(false);
                    me.active = false;
                }
            });
        }
        // Version specific methods
        if (Ext.lastRegisteredVersion.shortVersion > 407) {
            me.updateLayout();
        } else {
            me.updateEditState();
        }
    },

    /**
    * @override onTrigger2Click
    * eventhandler
    */
    onTrigger2Click: function (args) {
        this.clear();
    },

    /**
    * @private clear
    * clears the current search
    */
    clear: function () {
        var me = this;
        if (!me.clearable)
            return;
        me.onClear(false);
        me.clearValue();
        me.onShowClearTrigger(false);
        me.fireEvent('clear', me);
    }
});
```

Now that you have a combo that fires events for filter and clear you need to implement it. For that you need to know that not the grid filters or execute the loading, it is the store. Per default a store is configured with

```
remoteSort: false,  
remoteFilter: false, 
remoteGroup: false
```

So here is a example implementation

```
{
    xtype: 'filtercombo',
    id: 'iccombo',
    store: Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('Combostore'),
    fieldLabel: 'Short State',
    displayField: 'States',
    valueField: 'States',   
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    name: 'State',
    labelWidth: 125,
    anchor: '95%',
    recordField: 'ComboStoreFieldName',
    searchField: 'GridStoreFieldName',
    clearable: false,
    onSearch: function (me, value, field) {

        // You many also use component query to access your grid and call getStore()
        var store = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('YourStoreIdName');

        // Clear existing filters
            if (store.isFiltered()) {
            store.clearFilter(false);
            }
        // Build filter

        // Apply filter to store
        store.filter(field,value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sra, that is a nice solution. But what if I want to display all items by selecting 'ALL' option in combo box? How will the filter take it then?

Comment: @Harshrossi Ju just need to hit the 'x' button which appears as soon as a filter get applied and all filter get removed, meaning all records are shown. In addition you can check for the 'All' like `if (value == 'All' ) store.clearFilter();`

Answer (score 0):

on change of combobox value you can use filter method of store which you used in grid.

```
store.clearFIlter();
store.filter('name', valueOfCombobox);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the grid column list filter with multi-select combo then use below code...

```
                /**
             * Filter by a configurable app.view.common.tag.Tag
             * <p><b><u>Example Usage:</u></b></p>
             * <pre><code>
            var filters = Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters', {
                ...
                filters: [{
                    // required configs
                    type : 'combofilter',
                    dataIndex : 'myName',
                    options : ['aa','bb']

                    // optional configs
                    allowBlank: false, //default is true
                    fieldLabel: "Tag(s)"
                    ...
                }]
            });
             * </code></pre>
             */
            Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.filter.ComboFilter', {
                extend: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter',
                alias: 'gridfilter.combofilter',

                /**
                 * @cfg {String} iconCls
                 * The iconCls to be applied to the menu item.
                 * Defaults to <tt>'ux-gridfilter-text-icon'</tt>.
                 */
                iconCls : 'ux-gridfilter-text-icon',

                emptyText: 'Enter Filter Text...',
                selectOnFocus: true,
                width: 125,

                /**
                 * @private
                 * Template method that is to initialize the filter and install required menu items.
                 */
                init : function (config) {
                    Ext.applyIf(config, {
                        allowBlank: true,
                        queryMode: 'local',
                        displayField : 'name',
                        valueField : 'id',
                        store: (config.options == null ? [] : config.options),
                        multiSelect: true,
                        typeAhead: true,
                        itemId: 'valuesSelect',
                        emptyText : 'Select',
                        labelWidth: 29,
                        fieldLabel: '',
                        width: 300,
                        listeners: {
                            scope: this,
                            //keyup: this.onInputKeyUp,
                            el: {
                                click: function(e) {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    if (e.updateTask !== undefined) {
                                        e.updateTask.delay(this.updateBuffer);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            change: this.changeSelection
                        }
                    });

                    this.inputItem = Ext.create('app.view.common.tag.Tag', config);
                    this.menu.add(this.inputItem);
                    this.menu.showSeparator = false;
                    this.updateTask = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', this.fireUpdate, this);
                },

                /**
                 * @private
                 * Template method that is to get and return the value of the filter.
                 * @return {String} The value of this filter
                 */
                getValue : function () {
                    return this.inputItem.getValue();
                },

                /**
                 * @private
                 * Template method that is to set the value of the filter.
                 * @param {Object} value The value to set the filter
                 */
                setValue : function (value) {
                    this.inputItem.setValue(value);
                    this.fireEvent('update', this);
                },

                /**
                 * Template method that is to return <tt>true</tt> if the filter
                 * has enough configuration information to be activated.
                 * @return {Boolean}
                 */
                isActivatable : function () {
                    return this.inputItem.getValue().length > 0;
                },

                /**
                 * @private
                 * Template method that is to get and return serialized filter data for
                 * transmission to the server.
                 * @return {Object/Array} An object or collection of objects containing
                 * key value pairs representing the current configuration of the filter.
                 */
                getSerialArgs : function () {
                    return {type: 'list', value: this.getValue()};
                },

                /**
                 * Template method that is to validate the provided Ext.data.Record
                 * against the filters configuration.
                 * @param {Ext.data.Record} record The record to validate
                 * @return {Boolean} true if the record is valid within the bounds
                 * of the filter, false otherwise.
                 */
                validateRecord : function (record) {
                    var val = record.get(this.dataIndex);

                    if(typeof val != 'list') {
                        return (this.getValue().length === 0);
                    }

                    return val.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.getValue().toLowerCase()) > -1;
                },
                changeSelection: function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (this.updateTask !== undefined) {
                        this.updateTask.delay(this.updateBuffer);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please use Tag plugin of ExtJs and you need to add ComboFilter file in FiltersFeature. like ...

```
                Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature', {
                extend: 'Ext.grid.feature.Feature',
                alias: 'feature.filters',
                uses: [
                    'Ext.ux.grid.menu.ListMenu',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.menu.RangeMenu',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.BooleanFilter',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateFilter',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateTimeFilter',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.NumericFilter',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter',
                    'Ext.ux.grid.filter.ComboFilter'
                ],
```

It looks like ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0KiG.png)